# How to write N x N (with a multiplication symbol, for matrix dimensions)?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need to write something like NxN in LaTeX but I do not get how... How to do such thing?

Comment: `$N\times N$` or what do you mean?

Comment: Please make sure to accept the final solution, so that the question is marked as complete. I don't mind if Herbert posts his comment as an answer and you accept it. He was a little faster than me.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: You can try [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), it's very valuable for me, I am also a LaTeX beginner. You just draw on it and it gives you the LaTeX command for the symbol.

Comment: If you want to reduce space between `\times` operator and its operands, you may use: `$\medmuskip=0mu 3\times3$` within text, as outlined by http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41913/how-to-get-less-spacing-in-math-mode

Answer (score 243):

The `x` is done by `\times`. It must be used in mathmode:

```
$3\times4$

$N\times N$
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for text mode?

Comment: You can use \texttimes

Comment: @KhalidHussain: In text mode just write `$\times$`, but the numbers should be typeset in math mode as well, as it is done above in the answer post.

Comment: @MartinScharrer how do you achieve the dot for multiplication sign instead of `x`?

Comment: [Found it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55957/how-do-you-write-times)

Comment: Answering to Shimmy's comment: you might be looking for `\cdot`.

Comment: `$\times$` is not equivalent to `\texttimes` because the former will be set in the math font (as opposed to the main font). So if you're using a custom main font (and haven't bothered to set a matching math font) you may well prefer to use the text times.