# Keeping the distance between mathematical symbols consistent?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, letterspacing

In order to make text flushed both left and right, latex adjusts the distance between words, and to a lesser extent, the distance between characters within a word. This is good, however it also adjusts the spacing within mathematical formulae. I don't like this feature - can I reduce its effect, or perhaps turn it off completely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would have to modify the length registers that allow for stretch/shrink around math operators/relations, namely `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`. Their defaults are `4.0mu plus 2.0mu minus 4.0mu` and `5.0mu plus 5.0mu`. So adding

```
\setlength{\medmuskip}{1\medmuskip}% Formerly 4.0mu plus 2.0mu minus 4.0mu -> 4.0mu
\setlength{\thickmuskip}{1\thickmuskip}% Formerly 5.0mu plus 5.0mu -> 5.0mu
```

should work by stripping the glue. For more on math spacing around operators, see [How to change default for spacing around binary relations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55512/5764)

---

Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is some text with an equation in it: $f(x)=x^2+3x_0\cdot\sin x$ 
and the textual content continues into the second line. No other math
content is contained within this paragraph.

%\thinmuskip=3.0mu (without glue)
\setlength{\medmuskip}{1\medmuskip}% Formerly 4.0mu plus 2.0mu minus 4.0mu -> 4.0mu
\setlength{\thickmuskip}{1\thickmuskip}% Formerly 5.0mu plus 5.0mu -> 5.0mu

Here is some text with an equation in it: $f(x)=x^2+3x_0\cdot\sin x$ 
and the textual content continues into the second line. No other math
content is contained within this paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Since `\thinmuskip` is already void of glue, no further modifications is required. For a motivation of where these lengths are used, see the [`mathmode` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) (section **11 Space**, subsection *11.1 Math typesetting*, p 28).

`mu`skips are not supported by [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc), alternate calculations techniques (using plain TeX) are required to manipulate these lengths.

Comment: `\setlength` should not be used, because muskips are _not_ supported by package calc. Also there is no need for magic numbers, `\medmuskip=1\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip=1\thickmuskip` will do.

Comment: By the way, the fact that (for example) `\medmuskip=1\medmuskip` leaves the natural length of `\medmuskip` the same but keeps it from stretching or shrinking is mentioned on page 100 of Lamport's LaTeX 2e manual: "Multiplying a length command by a number destroys its elasticity, producing a rigid length." I thought I'd mention this because I'm not sure how common the knowledge of this trick is.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the `mathmode` documentation is dead.

Comment: @polynomial_donut: Thanks; fixed! The "package" has moved location and is considered obsolete. :-|

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to resetting the parameters it is sometimes more convenient to box the expression so it is set to natural width, either with an explicit box, or within the math, just using `{}`.

[image]

Note the math only stretched on the second row in this plain tex example.

```
X\hbox{words here $a + b$ and here}X

X\hbox spread 1cm{words here $a + b$ and here}X


X\hbox spread 1cm{words here \hbox{$a + b$} and here}X

X\hbox spread 1cm{words here ${a + b}$ and here}X

\bye
```