# How to modfiy spacing for inline math?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, inline

I want to reduce spacing between operators in inline math. If I add the follwing lines to the peamble it affects both inline and display math modes.

```
\thinmuskip=0mu
\medmuskip=0mu
\thickmuskip=0mu
```

How can I limit the effect to inline math without using separate groups for each piece of text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you want the spacing *that* tight?

You could use `\everymath` to insert the declarations at the start of every technically inline expression but this will include many build up constructs (arrays, AMS alignments, that use displaymode in inline math.

If you enter inline math using `\(` rather than `$` it is easy you can go

```
\let\oldmath\(
\DeclareRobustCommand\({%
\oldmath\thinmuskip=0mu
\medmuskip=0mu
\thickmuskip=0mu
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `\everymath` and it worked for me. You now the lack of space in conference papers, in fact I don't set all to zero.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following just works fine:

```
\everymath{
    \medmuskip=0.5\medmuskip
    \thickmuskip=0.5\thickmuskip
}
```

Compiled from [Decrease length of spaces in inline math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499221/decrease-length-of-spaces-in-inline-math) and Heiko Oberdiek's comment in
 [Keeping the distance between mathematical symbols consistent?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83746/keeping-the-distance-between-mathematical-symbols-consistent).