# Decrease length of spaces in inline math

Tags: spacing, inline

It is a requirement of the journal I'm submitting to that inline math be formatted as `$x\!=\!3$`, i.e. that we insert a thin negative space around operators.

Is there a way that I can set this document-wide, so that I don't have to go over my 30-page manuscript line-by-line?

Let me emphasize that in principle, I want to be able to edit the spacing for *inline math only*.

Comment: Should the normal spacing of operators be kept the original in display math? Also, should the negative space be added on top of the normal spacing, or should it be the only spacing between operators and operands?

Comment: Try some like `\thickmuskip1.75mu`

Comment: @siracusa yes, in display math, the original spacing should be kept. I am not sure whether the possible duplicate question addresses this. Not sure about your second question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\everymath` and `\everydisplay`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newmuskip\normalthickmuskip
\newmuskip\normalthinmuskip
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \normalthickmuskip=\thickmuskip
  \normalthinmuskip=\thinmuskip
}
\everymath{%
  \thickmuskip=\muexpr\normalthickmuskip-(1\normalthinmuskip plus 1\normalthinmuskip)\relax
}
\everydisplay{\thickmuskip=\normalthickmuskip}
\let\texdisplaystyle\displaystyle
\renewcommand{\displaystyle}{\texdisplaystyle\the\everydisplay}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} % just for easing comparisons with below formulas
$a=b$
\end{center}
\[
a=b
\]
\begin{align*}
a&=b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\displaystyle` is necessary because `amsmath` environments don't generally evaluate `\everydisplay`.

[image]

This will affect *all* relations, not only `=`. You may possibly want to decrease also `\medmuskip` in inline formulas.

Answer (score 3):

Since the value of `\thickmuskip` -- the parameter which governs the amount of whitespace that's inserted between adjacent math atoms of type `math-ord` and `math-rel` -- is `5mu` in all document classes I'm familiar with, and since `\!` inserts `-3mu` of (negative) whitespace, you may achieve your journal's formatting objective by issuing the instruction

```
\everymath{\thickmuskip=2mu minus 2mu}
```

in the preamble. Note that the value of `\thickmuskip` that's employed in displayed equations is *not* affected by this directive. (Aside: If the `amsmath` package is loaded, then you will need to reset the value of `\thickmuskip` to its default value explicitly for displayed equations, along the lines shown in [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499381/5001).)

I can't help but remark that the journal's requirement to reduce the value of `\thickmuskip` while not also requiring a reduction in the value of `\medmuskip` -- the parameter which governs the amount of whitespace that's inserted between adjacent math atoms of type `math-ord` and `math-bin` (such as `+` and `-`) -- verges on being bizarre or preposterous. Take, say, the equation

```
1+1=2
```

The default value of `\medmuskip` is `4mu`. I think it's a very bad idea to reduce `\thickmuskip` to `2mu` while leaving `\medmuskip` unchanged. I would therefore suggest that you also execute something like

```
\everymath{\medmuskip=1.5mu minus 1.5mu}
```

in the preamble

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$1+1=2$ --- normal look

\everymath{\thickmuskip=2mu minus 2mu}
$1+1=2$ --- bizarre look

\everymath{\medmuskip=1.5mu minus 1.5mu\thickmuskip=2mu minus 2mu}
$1+1=2$ --- cramped (but not bizarre) look
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499381/): While it did change the spacing the way I wanted, it introduced regressions into URL rendering (characters like ., -, / got wider), also affecting `\nolinkurl` and links in biblatex. I fixed it by adding

```
\def\Hurl{\begingroup \everymath{}\Url}
```

to the preamble.