# spacing between symbols in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The following code will

```
\begingroup
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\scriptsize
$XXXXXXX(XXXX(A,B,C),XXXX(D,E,F)) \leftarrow XXXXXX(A,B,C) \wedge XXXXXX(D,E,F) \wedge     XXXXX(XX(A,B),XX(D,E)) \wedge XXXXX(XX(B,C),XX(E,F)) \wedge XXXXXX(XXX(A,B,C),XXX(D,E,F)).$
\endgroup
```

format my rule like this:
[image]

I really do not like this because it has the tendency to stretch the expressions to cover a whole line, which is absolutely unnecessary. I just want some natural spacing there even if it did not expand to cover the whole line. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are probably interested in removing the stretch/shrink associated with the space around operators/operands in math mode. For this, see [Keeping the distance between mathematical symbols consistent?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83746/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This look, maybe?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\scriptstyle
\begin{array}{l@{\quad}r}
XXXXXXX(XXXX(A,B,C),XXXX(D,E,F)) &\leftarrow \\
XXXXXX(A,B,C) \quad \wedge \quad XXXXXX(D,E,F) &\wedge\\
XXXXX(XX(A,B),XX(D,E)) & \wedge \\
XXXXX(XX(B,C),XX(E,F)) & \wedge \\
XXXXXX(XXX(A,B,C),XXX(D,E,F)).\\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

If `\quad` provides too much space for you, try `\mkern n mu` -- `\mkern18mu` corresponds to `\quad`.

---

*Addendum*: If you want the end-of-line `\rightarrow` and `\wedge` symbols to be separated from the material to the right by the same amount (say, `\quad`), a single column in the `array` might be what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\scriptstyle\begin{array}{l}
XXXXXXX(XXXX(A,B,C),XXXX(D,E,F)) \quad\leftarrow \\
XXXXXX(A,B,C) \quad \wedge \quad XXXXXX(D,E,F) \quad\wedge\\
XXXXX(XX(A,B),XX(D,E)) \quad \wedge \\
XXXXX(XX(B,C),XX(E,F)) \quad \wedge \\
 XXXXXX(XXX(A,B,C),XXX(D,E,F)).\\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not so satisfactory, how do I shrink the space between my expression and "and" symbol on the third and forth line?

Comment: @user1935724 - Does the look in the addendum meet your needs?

Comment: @Mcio, I've accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make TeX decide for the line breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\lrand}{\mathrel{\land}} % a relation, while \wedge=\land is an operation

\newenvironment{mrule}
 {\relpenalty=0 \flushleft$\displaystyle}
 {$\endflushleft}

\newenvironment{mruleA}
 {\relpenalty=0
  \quote
  \raggedright
  $\displaystyle}
 {$\endquote}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{mrule}
XXXXXXX(XXXX(A,B,C),XXXX(D,E,F)) \gets
XXXXXX(A,B,C) \lrand
XXXXXX(D,E,F) \lrand
XXXXX(XX(A,B),XX(D,E)) \lrand
XXXXX(XX(B,C),XX(E,F)) \lrand
XXXXXX(XXX(A,B,C),XXX(D,E,F)).
\end{mrule}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{mruleA}
XXXXXXX(XXXX(A,B,C),XXXX(D,E,F)) \gets
XXXXXX(A,B,C) \lrand
XXXXXX(D,E,F) \lrand
XXXXX(XX(A,B),XX(D,E)) \lrand
XXXXX(XX(B,C),XX(E,F)) \lrand
XXXXXX(XXX(A,B,C),XXX(D,E,F)).
\end{mruleA}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer the second approach, leaving some space on the left (and right). If you want to possibly reach the right margin, change the definition into

```
\newenvironment{mruleA}
 {\relpenalty=0
  \list{}{\leftmargin=\leftmargini \rightmargin=0pt}
  \raggedright\item\relax$\displaystyle}
 {$\endlist}
```

By setting `\relpenalty=0` we tell TeX that breaking at relation symbols is OK. Using `\lrand` instead of `\wedge` ensures the same spacing around ∧ and ← (note that `\gets` is the same as `\leftarrow`, but shorter to type).

[image]