# Controlling horizontal spacing in math mode in text

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

I am using the most recent release of TexLive on my MacBook Air.  I am using the packages `amsmath`, `amssymb`, `scalefnt`, `graphicx`,and `subcaption` in addition to a journal's package.

Like a previous query [How to get less spacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41913/how-to-get-less-spacing-in-math-mode), I want to reduce the white space in math mode but only when an equation occurs in text, as in `$a=b.$`  I don't want to automatically reduce the white space when in display-math mode, such as

```
$$a=b$$
```

or

```
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{align}
```

I know that I can do various things in individual equations such as 
`$a{=}b$` or `$ a \!=\! b,$` but I don't want to have to do it each time,
and the journal might insist on changes in publication, or perhaps 
my co-author will want to do things differently for some other purpose.

I couldn't see how to use `\newcommand` or `\stackrel` in a way that makes such a distinction between equations in text and equations in displaymath, but it ought to be simple using {displaystyle} or something similar.  I couldn't figure it out.

Help?

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: It's a rather strange request and no obvious way to easily support it if you use `$` to enter math mode. If you use the standard latex alternative `\(a=b\)` then it is easy as you just need to redefine `\(` to change the spacing.

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't change the spacing around the ``equals" sign, would it?  That was the issue.

Comment: @Werner @DavidCarlisle Actually, I have never seen anybody in my field (theoretical physics) ever use   ` \(  a=b \) `   instead of ` $ a=b $` . Why use 4 keystrokes when 2 will do? – MidwestGeek 20 mins ago

Comment: @Werner @DavidCarlisle   Sorry. Don't know markdown language; another try.   Actually, I have never seen anybody in my field (theoretical physics) ever use  
     ` \( `  a=b `\) `  
instead of  
    ` $ a=b $ `.  
Why use 4 keystrokes when 2 will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\everymath{\if@display\else\thickmuskip=2mu plus 2mu\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}% just to show the effect
$a=b$
\end{center}
\[
a=b
\]

\end{document}
```

Alternatively (and preferably), but this requires using `\(...\)` for inline math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\(}{$}{$\thickmuskip=2mu plus 2mu }{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}% just to show the effect
\(a=b\)
\end{center}
\[
a=b
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that `$$...$$` will produce reduced spaces, if the first method is used. But this construction should never be used in LaTeX anyway.

[image]

Comment: I will give your first alternative a try. It seems to work well and is configurable with having to type  ` \\(  ...  \\) ` .  Thanks!

Comment: of course, this affects the spacing around all relations in this class of symbols.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Undoubtedly