# How to eliminate extra space around binary math operator

Tags: math-operators, operator-space

As an example, consider the plus sign (+). The code `$x + y$` generates `x + y`. How can you make it look like `x+y`? In other words, how can you treat + like a letter rather than an operator? I'm looking for a local solution rather than a global one.

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x + y$
\end{document}
```

Comment: potential duplicate: [How to get less spacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41913)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x + y$

$x{+}y$
\end{document}
```