# How do you write "times"?

Tags: math-operators

I come from Norway, and here the formatting of maths are a little bit different than in the U.S. and the UK. If you want to factorize 25, you know that it is 5 times 5. How would you write this with LaTeX? In Norway we would write 5⋅5, and as far as I've seen, with LaTeX, you would write: `$5\times 5$` ( 5 x 5 )

Is there a difference, or is one of them wrong? Which one actually means times?

Comment: Use `$5\cdot 5$`.

Comment: It depends on the context and the tradition. BTW: If you are native from Norway, you might be able to read my Danish LaTeX book, just googl my name and `latexbog`

Comment: Yepp, I can. I'll do :) Danish and Norwegian is written almost the same, as you know. :) Great to have a LaTeX course in my "almost native" language!

Comment: @daleif But, I'm using it only for my website, and to process maths with a PHP-script. I don't use LaTeX as a language.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a Norwegian speciality!  Using a dot for multiplication is quite common in mathematics beyond school-level.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Ok. But why do I see the \times so often over at math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: According to the omnipotent Wikipedia "The middle dot is standard in the United States, the United Kingdom, and other countries where the period is used as a decimal point. In other countries that use a comma as a decimal point, either the period or a middle dot is used for multiplication." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Notation_and_terminology)

Comment: Yes, we do use a comma instead of a period to indicate decimals.

Comment: @50ndr33 No idea.  Maybe because lots of the people there have school-level maths so people use `\times` to ensure there's no misunderstanding.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Hvilken bruker du, personlig, da?

Comment: @50ndr33 Det avhenger.  Personlig, bruker jeg det meste ingen ting, slik `x y`.  Jeg bruker `\cdot` kun hvis det er nødvendig å klare noe, f.eks `2 \cdot 3`, eller jeg vil skire at studentene skjønner at jeg menner å multipliserer de tingene.  (Beklager at norsken min er litt dårlig)

Comment: In Spain  \times is used by children at school.
\cdot is used by mathemacians, scientifics and engineers.
\cdot has two advantages: · it's shorter and cleaner and it can't be confused with the ex letter.

Comment: I am well-versed in math, and the following is fairly global.  Children tend to use the "x", which in latex is \times. Older folks use a dot, which in latex is \cdot.  There is an actual distinction in math, where the dot means "scalar product" and the "x" means "matrix multiplication". To "regular folks", the scalar product is the "normal" multiplication they think of.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can use `$5\cdot 5$` to create the way used in Norway. I don't know the mathematical difference as I'm not that firm in mathematics ;-)
But this is a way to just create the output you want.

Comment: Personally I use the `\times` symbol only in three different occasions: (1) the cross product –vector product– (e.g., `\vec j \times \vec k = \vec{\imath}`); (2) to write dimensions (e.g., `$3 \times 3$ matrix`); (3) to write numbers in scientific notation –to visually know if the whole expression is a number or a multiplication– (e.g., `2.5 \times 10^3 \cdot 3 \times 10^2` is a multiplication of two “scientific” numbers). For everything else I use the usual `·` (`\cdot`).

Answer (score 6):

It both means the same, multiplication. The used symbol depends on your location. If you want to have a centred dot, you can use `\cdot` instead.

Comment: But, if they're all correct, and means multiplication: Why is the dot called cdot, instead of something more like multiplication like times is?

Comment: `cdot` means centered dot. With regards to the choice of calling name, well that is left to how the initial writer decided it to be.

Comment: @50ndr33: There are other dots as well, like `.` (a period), `\ddot` as an accent (and `\dddot` and `\ddddot`, provided by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), I think).

Comment: And `\dot` is for [Newton-style differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton.27s_notation). For example, `\( \dot x \)`.

Comment: @Marco -- if i remember rightly from a basic mechanics course, many years ago, a "dot product" is a scalar product (like `$5 \cdot 5$`), and a "cross product" is a vector product (my memory isn't good enough to come up with a decent example).  this level of distinction isn't recognized until after secondary school.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the rest of the answers, that `\cdot` is the way to have multiplication represented by a dot, as seem to be usual in many countries.  However, I would suggest that when dealing with a notation that is language, country or region specific, you define your own command.  In this case you can for example do `\let\times\cdot` in the preamble of your document.

That way, if your document ever gets translated to another language, the translator does not have to go and change all the math equations and formulas, they just need to replace your `\let` command by, for example, `\let\times\longrightarrow` if they are translating to a language in which multiplication is denoted by a long right arrow.

Answer (score 3):

`amsmath` package defines a `\dots` command, which is similar to the existing `\ldots` command. In Math, the `\cdot` command can be used to represent the centered dot multiplication symbol as opposed to the conventional `\times` symbol and similar to `\ldots` we have `\cdots`.

Hence to get the centered dot in your example, you need to input:

`$5\cdot 5$`