# Typeset a factor in math mode ("A is 3.5x larger than B.")

Tags: math-mode

I want to express "A is $3.5x$ (3.5 times) larger than B."

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A is $3.5x$ / $3.5\times$ (3.5 times) larger than B.
\end{document}
```

If I understand correctly, then `$3.5x$` typesets "x" as a variable rather than "times". In correspondence with [How do you write "times"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55957/how-do-you-write-times#comment230485_55958), I also feel that `$3.5\times$` is incorrect.

Comment: I'd just write is in words as 3.5× looks odd on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ever you do: Define a command first which you may redefine later on. The `$3.5x$`-version is wrong for sure. Here are three versions, I personally think acceptable:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\newcommand*{\factor}[1]{$\num{#1}\mathrel\times$}
%\newcommand*{\factor}[1]{$\num{#1}\times$}
\newcommand*{\factor}[1]{\num{#1} times}

\begin{document}
$A$ is \factor{3.5} larger than $B$.
\end{document}
```