# How to write postfix times symbol

Tags: symbols

Sometimes you want to say "the new method is 18x faster" pronounced "eighteen times faster", how do you produce that cross in latex?

I tried

```tex
the new method is 18\times faster
```

But that italicises everything after it

What's the typesetting standard to use? To be honest, `$\times$` doesn't look exactly right in the first place.

Comment: `$` starts or ends math mode.  So if you have `$\times`, then you've started math mode, but not ended it.  That will give you strange errors later on.  gigair's answer shows how you would properly end math mode.

Comment: @Teepeemm ~~i didn't have `$\times`~~ Oh sorry, I see the confusion caused by the typo in the last sentence. I have never put `$\times` into my document though.

Comment: Did you have a look at `\texttimes? (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15131/44119)

Comment: If you say `18\times` there will be an error --- TeX will suggest to add a `$` because it's seeing a math-mode thing. If you run in `nonstopmode` you will have the same effect as writing `18$\times`. Then TeX will add another `$` (with another error) at the end of the paragraph: this is why it "italicises everything after it" (in reality is math mode, not italics). So, never ignore errors... and better not run with `nosnstopmode`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a command, even if you use this once. This way you can change your mind whenever you please and are not tied to a particular representation.

I propose two realizations, take your pick or experiment in different ways.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\grA}[1]{#1$\mskip1mu\times$}
\newcommand{\grB}[1]{#1\textsf{\,x}}

\begin{document}

This method is \grA{10} faster.

This method is \grB{10} faster.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried with `\def\x{\textsf{x}}`, but it gets rid of the following space. Producing 10xfaster instead of 10x faster like your rendering. Do you know why?

Comment: Making it a non-ASCII character fixes it, I'm using `\def\×{\textsf{x}}` now

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
the new method is 18$\times$ faster
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the error I had. I'm not sure I like how it looks though.